# Emit an event after certain number of days in Hyperledger composer

Tags: node.js, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

An asset called `Contract` have `contract_start_date` and `contract_end_date` properties in the model file. I want to emit an event after `contract_end_date`.

The model file:

```js
asset Contract identified by contractId {
       o String contractId
       o DateTime contract_start_date
       o DateTime contract_end_date
}

transaction set_Dates {
    --> Contract contract
    o DateTime start_date
    o DateTime end_date
}

event end_Date_Reached { 
    o String message
}
```

```js
/** 
 * In the logic.js file 
 */
 
 async function setDate (tx) { 
   tx.contract.contract_start_date = tx.start_date;
   tx.contract.contract_end_date = tx.end_date; 
   
   // get the Contract asset from registry
  let contractRegistry = await getAssetRegistry('org.test.sample.Contract');
  await contractRegistry.update(tx.contract);  // update the registry
 }
```

How do I emit the `end_Date_Reached` event by checking the value of `contract_end_date` property? Any help will be appreciated!